# Timed out retrying after 30000ms: Expected to find element: someElement, but never found it

Tags: html, css, cypress

I'm trying to select an ancestor of an element using code below.

```
cy.contains('someText').parentsUntil('[role="row"]').find('div.ag-header-cell.ag-header-cell-sortable.flex-grow-1.flex-shrink-0.ag-focus-managed');
```

But I get following error.

```
Timed out retrying after 30000ms: Expected to find element: div.ag-header-cell.ag-header-cell-sortable.flex-grow-1.flex-shrink-0.ag-focus-managed, but never found it.
```

This is the output printed to my console for this command.
[image: output of console]

The element at index [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWVMH.png) is the element I am looking for. It exists in the output of "parentsUntil" command, but does not exist when I want to "find" it. However the element of index 1 "div.ag-header-cell-comp-wrapper" is found without any problem.

Here is the HTML of the elements, from "cy.contains('someText')" back to the "parentsUntil('[role="row"]')".

[image]

Why cannot it be found while it exists in the output of "parentsUntil" command?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML of the elements between your `parentsUntil` and `get` commands?

Comment: @agoff I added the HTML.

Comment: In the future, please use text snippets instead of images - it is a SO best practice https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11625850

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just that `.find()` is looking for a ***child*** or descendent of whatever is in that list yielded (i.e the list in dev console after you click the command).

But `<div.ag-header-cell>` is the top-most element that gets selected by `.parentsUntil()` so it's not a child of anything in that list.

You could go a couple of ways:

- just pick the last in the list

  ```js
  cy.contains('someText')
    .parentsUntil('[role="row"]')
    .last()
    .should('have.class', 'ag-header-cell')
  ```

- or go to the `[role="row"]` using `.parent()`, if explicit `.find()` is needed

  ```js
  cy.contains('someText')
    .parentsUntil('[role="row"]')
    .parent()                         // now [role="row"] is in the list
    .find('div.ag-header-cell')
  ```